# How to get File Version Information with Java and Sigar

Tags: java, sigar

I'm attempting to write a program that will utilize sigar in order to find a file's version information. I see that org.hyperic.sigar.win32 has a class FileVersion which has a method getFileVersion(), but I'm unclear how to pass in the location of the file I want to find the version for.

I think it would be something like this:

```
 String exeFile = "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe"
 String strFileInfo = new FileVersion().getFileVersion(exeFile);
```

but this is certainly not correct.